# How can we compare two strings?

Tags: string-manipulation, sorting

In Python, you can do this:

```
"ab" > "ac"
```

which returns `False`.

In Mathematica, it doesn't evaluate.

But why? These are literal strings, not symbols.

Comment: Just from the question description, I can not figure out what is comparing two strings.

Comment: But `1>2` works, there's also no indication of what is comparing two numbers.

Comment: With due respect, comparison of two numbers is common sense taught as early as in primary mathematics, but that of strings is not.

Comment: Number and string are both "atoms" in the language, so why are they treated differently in this case? Just because one is taught in primary school, and the other is not? Just wondering if there's a deeper reason for that. It seems odd a programming language would depend its design on school curriculum, rather than its own construct.

Comment: If strings should be comparable in the way of numbers, just because both of them are "atoms", so should symbols. Maybe this question should be forwarded to Wolfram himself :).

Comment: True, symbols should be too, since "atoms" consists of numbers, strings, and symbols. In fact, that's what a lot of programming language is capable of: operator overloading. I wonder is if Mathematica can do the same thing, to overload "+" to expand its behavior from numbers only.

Comment: or ">". The point is to expand the built-in operator's capability, depending on its operands type. So the common built-in operator is reused, not to invent more and more custom operators.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`AlphabeticOrder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AlphabeticOrder.html) can compare strings alphabetically (or by other conventions used in dictionaries by various languages).

Comment: While alphabetical ordering is works great for this simple example, things start to get weird once you cross into alpha-numeric strings. For that, you need lexicographic ordering.